# Scroll SVN-stored text file served by Apache

Tags: apache, svn, browser, apache2

I have a 1.7.9 SVN server exposed via Apache. It uses apache2-svn which allows to specify revision number as a part of the URL like this (for r65):

`https://SERVER:PORT/REPO/FILE?p=65`

I'd like to add a parameter to a query string that allows scrolling the file or even better - highlighting a range in the file. So users can send links pointing to "revision 65, lines 110-125".

Any ideas? The SVN stores only regular text files. Do browsers even support scrolling an arbitrary text file? Or would I need to transform the file into a HTML document? Any ready to use solution?

Cheers,
Pawel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Built-in Apache's SVN repository browsing feature](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.browsing) is very simple and minimalistic. It does not allow you to specify the particular string to navigate to. The available URL syntax allows

- viewing / downloading a particular file:

  `https://svn.domain.com/svn/MyProject/trunk/README.txt`
- viewing / downloading a particular file in revision 321:

  `https://svn.domain.com/svn/MyProject/trunk/README.txt?r=321`
- viewing / downloading a particular file, which is not available in the youngest revision, by specifying [*peg revision*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html):

  `https://svn.domain.com/svn/MyProject/trunk/FILE_ID.DIZ?p=123`
- combining both of the above methods you can tune the view.

If you want more browsing features, install 3-rd party repository browsing UI. Take a closer look at ViewVC, WebSVN and Sventon.